# Setting padding does not update view

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-scrollview

I'm creating a custom view that consist of multiple framelayouts and a scrolllayout. The scrollview has a top padding and this padding is supposed to be equal the combined heights of the framelayouts (see illustation).
[image]

```
       framelayoutA.addOnLayoutChangeListener { v, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _ ->
        if (v.height == framelayoutAHeight) return@addOnLayoutChangeListener
        framelayoutAHeight = v.height
        framelayoutAGuideline.setGuidelineBegin(framelayoutAHeight)
        framelayoutBGuideline.setGuidelineBegin(framelayoutAHeight)
        val padding = framelayoutAHeight + framelayoutBHeight
        Log.d("ParallaxScrollingView", "framelayoutAHeight = $framelayoutAHeight")
        Log.d("ParallaxScrollingView", "padding = $padding")
        scrollView.setPadding(0, padding, 0, 0)

    }
```

In order to set this padding, i need the framelayouts' height, which i get in `onLayoutChangeListener`. My problem is, that framelayout A's height is updated twice resulting in `onLayoutChangeListener` being called twice. The first time it is called, the top padding for the scrollview is set and updated correctly, however the second time it is called, the new top padding is set, but the view is not updated. There are several seconds between the two layout changes. Does anyone have an idea why the padding is not updated?

Comment: *this padding is supposed to be equal the combined heights of the framelayouts* what's the point of this

Comment: im using `android:clipToPadding="false"` on the scrolllayout, so that the scrolllayout scrolls over the framelayouts

Comment: have you tried using `invalidateAll()`

Comment: i have the same problem, i call `SetPadding` in `LayoutChange` and padding is not updated. but when i refresh layout (e.g. re enter page) then i see that view has updated padding... Calling `Invalidate` or `requestLayout` doesn't help.